# Where to find build_tests command?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, distribute, python-2to3

When I was reading examples for testing a package in multiple pythons with tox I found about a command `"build_tests"` that would put (`2to3`'d) test files in `build/` directory. I could also google it in some projects' `tox.ini` files and some gentoo ebuilds, but I still don't know which package installs this command. I have python 3.2, last nosetests and last distribute, but `"python setup.py build_tests"` still gives error.

So what do I have to install to get this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did some more lookup and I found that at least in nose there is a custom script that adds this command. So I will probably have to copy this idea if I want to have tests for py3k.